# C# - skip generics

Tags: c#, generics, skip

How I can pass parameters of a generic type in my methods?

```
public Type<T, U, V> { ... }

public void Method(??? arg) // where ??? is Type<T, U, V>
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Dont' get our question. Can you please provide more details about what you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

Carry the generic parameters to your method definition

```
public void Method<T,U,V>(Type<T,U,V> arg) // where ??? is Type<T, U, V>
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to make the method itself generic:

```
public void Method<T, U, V>(Type<T, U, V> arg) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: http://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/1394332737Go-Deeper-Inception-Movie.jpg

Answer (score 3):

```
public Type<T, U, V> { ... }

public void Method<T, U, V>(Type<T, U, V> arg)
{
    ...
}
```